# Событие при выборе выпадающих элементов в инпуте

Tags: события, javascript

Здравствуйте, при клике в форме на инпуты браузер показывает список из истории, например когда кликаешь на email выпадает список email'ов, так вот, как прикрепить событие на выборку из списка, сделал:

```
onchange="functionNaem();"
```

не сработал ни на фф, хр ни на опере а про ие вообще молчу. Вообщем как решить?

PS у меня сейчас стоит onkeyup="" , т.е. при вводе каждую букву обрабатывает. А вот когда юзер выбирает из выпадающих элементов пока ничего не работает. Вот остается сделать либо создать событию при выборе из выпадающих элементов либо вообще запретить браузеру показать список при клике на инпут, так что буду рад если хотя бы подскажете как запретить браузеру при клике на инпут показывать список(емайлов, имен и т.д.)

Comment: событие input, только пожалуйста не вешайте в разметке, смотреть больно.

Comment: @eicto, не понял я вас, вообще вы о чем?

Comment: @bemulima [об этом](http://jsfiddle.net/75kNL/)

Comment: @eicto, клево, спасибо! то что надо. В разметке в имеете в виду, что прям в инпут нельзя писать, как например onclick=""?